# This project cannot be viewed in the object browser because it is unavailable or not yet built

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013

I have a VS2013 solution that has many projects all C# with framework 4.5
When I try and rebuild all projects in the solution I get an error message

```
This project cannot be viewed in the object browser because it is unavailable or not yet built
```

I note that in the start up project the references to the other DLLS appear as though the DLLs are missing.

I can actually get the solution to run by building each project one at a time, and then double clicking the reference in the start up project.

Eventually I have gotten rid of all the bad reference icons in the start up project and the solution will run.

However as soon as I rebuild the whole solution the bad references re-appear.

Strangely  Build works, but Re-Build doesn't, and Clean and Re-build doesn't.

I do have the following set up.

```
Project Templates References Project DomainLayer
Project DataLayer References Project Templates and Project DomainLayer
```

Thus VS needs to build DomainLayer first then Templates then DataLayer.... perhaps it can't work this out?

What is going on?

Comment: I've got the same thing.  Did you fix?  I can't get it to go away.  Changed it to every framework version and same result.  I remove a reference and add it back and the path is immediately empty in the reference properties.

Comment: @JeffBorden  I don't fully remember what I did, I don't have the problem any more.  I wonder if it was that i needed to set Copy Local to true as well.  I see I did tick Sandeep's answer.

Answer (score 2):

Although you could build projects individually, but cannot rebuild solution. It sounds to be problem with target framework. Go to project properties and ensure you're targeting Framework 4.5 for all projects. Somewhere in some project this might be missing.

Comment: I repeat they are all 4.5

Answer (score 0):

Try uninstalling the NuGet packages, ensuring all of the project references are removed, restarting VS, and installing the packages again. Afterwards, check that the references don't have any warning icons.

My only guess is that this happens due to some type of bug or due to manual modification of project files which causes VS to install and reference NuGet packages incorrectly.

Answer (score 0):

I use vs2019 and have the same problem

My solution:

1. Upgrade .net framework
2. Close visual studio
3. Delete folder packages in solution
4. Open project again and rebuild solution

Hope useful for you.